# Situational help needed - Teasing colleagues

Tags: communication, work-environment, team, bullying

I faced a bad situation few days back. On a team outing, I asked a bad question and totally unaware that my question was wrong. My colleagues laughed out so loud and teased me so badly that I felt so embarrassed.

Few days later, my colleagues again teased me about the same question on a different situation. This scenario is continuing until now and my colleagues are teasing me with my question on every possible situations.

Caveat:  I was thinking to talk with my Manager about this situation, however, my Manager has already fired 5 people from the team for some silly reasons. I am confused about handling this situation.Any suggestion will be greatly helpful!

Comment: Was the question work related or personal? What would you like to see happen?

Comment: It is y workplace related. It's all happening at my workplace. I am so embarrassed to get teased everytime :(

Comment: Do you want your colleagues to stop teasing you? Or is there something else? We can only help if you have a concrete goal in mind.

Comment: Yes. I want my Colleagues to stop teasing me.

Comment: Join them. Teasing would stop if you no longer react to it.

Comment: What? Can you explain?

Comment: @PM77-1 Teasing should stop not because Akansha doesn't react to it, but because it creates a hostile work environment.

Comment: They sound childlike, and children have a short attention span. Ignore it as best you can & eventually they will find some new entertainment.  However, if you really don't like the atmosphere, you might consider leaving. Personally, I would ask them to stop; if they failed to, I would polish my CV & give them the sharp edge of my tongue, but that might not be your way

Answer (score 3):

"Hey all, I know I said something silly on the team outing, but it's stopped being funny now. Please drop it."

Only go to your manager (or HR or whoever) once you've at least made an effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: And the main person to tease me is my Manager!

Answer (score 1):

If your manager is among those teasing you, then you go to your manager, and tell them to stop immediately. If they don't stop you go to HR. From your colleagues you can expect a certain amount of stupidity. Your manager has no excuse. That's what he or she is manager for.